# C# Application Lags when Communicating over TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, lag

I am making a simple communication between a Client Application and a Server Application.

Server:

```
TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.66"),9000);
tcp.Start();
TextBox.Text += "Start Listening \r\n"; //1
Socket s = tcp.AcceptSocket();
TextBox.Text += "Client Has Connected \r\n";
```

The lagging occurs the following way, String number 1 will not show up until a Client has connected, the application simply freezes, I can't even drag the window.

I tried adding a delay:

```
TextBox.Text += "Start Listening \r\n";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Socket s = tcp.AcceptSocket();
TextBox.Text += "Client Has Connected \r\n";
```

Still this won't allow the first message to be printed and THEN search for sockets. The application keeps on freezing until a Client is connected.

Comment: You're blocking your UI thread.  Don't do that.  Read this: http://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a specific reason for using plain sockets rather than `WCF`?

Comment: @programmer93 - If he's so green that he doesn't understand thread blocking, WCF is going to be WAY too over his head.

Comment: @MystereMan Well I looked at his reputation and thought he should know the basics of multithreading :)

Comment: Something tells me that rep cam from non C# related questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this listening on a thread? If not you are locking the gui from updating.

```
void StartListener()
{
    System.Threading.Thread listenerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ListenerThread));
    listenerThread.IsBackground = true; // Causes the thread to close if the app is closed
    listenerThread.Start();
}

void ListenerThread()
{
    TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.66"),9000);
    tcp.Start();
    UpdateStatus("Start Listening \r\n"); //1
    Socket s = tcp.AcceptSocket();
    UpdateStatus("Client Has Connected \r\n"); //1

    // Listen for more messages, or close the listener here.
}

void UpdateStatus(string message)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { UpdateStatus(message); });
    else
        Textbox.Text = message;
}
```

Comment: I like it how the non-safe version of `UpdateStatus` is calling itself in a safe way. But wouldn't it be just easier to update the textbox inside the delegate instead?

Comment: Yes you could. I always call the method in case the function grows larger. In this case, it could easily be done, so yes.